# Trying to put an int player Position on a board (grid)

Tags: java

```java
public static void changePlayerPos(String[][] board,int playerPos) {
        if(playerPos<100&&playerPos>10) {
            int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(playerPos).substring(0, 1));
            int secondDigit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(playerPos).substring(1, 1));
            board[firstDigit][secondDigit-1] = "P   ";
        }
    }
```

So this is my code, and I am having errors when I am calling the method

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>   at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
>   at trial.changePlayerPos(trial.java:68)
>   at trial.main(trial.java:23)
> ```

Can anyone help me find the error?

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `String.valueOf(playerPos).substring(1, 1)`? Don't guess - look at it in the debugger or log it.

Comment: And take a good look at the [`javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) for `substring`; pay close attention to the meaning of the second argument.

Comment: i see i see, ty vm

Answer (score 0):

You should read in more details **substring** function's [documentation](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-substring).

Keep in mind that when it comes to its parameters, start index is inclusive and end index is exclusive.